# Admob ad will not load. Error 2. It worked before but suddenly stopped

Tags: java, android, admob

Here is the entire class that I am trying to load a banner ad into (createAd() method does the work)

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    private HomeView homeView;
    private ImageView playButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

//        playButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.playButton);
//        playButton.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
//                R.drawable.play));
//        setListener();
        setContentView(R.layout.home_main);
        createAd();

    }

    private void setListener (){
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                playButton.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.play2));
                playGame();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAd(){
        setContentView(R.layout.home_main);
        AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.bottomAd);
        AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice("FEACCF89D31180ABDD853C9C3DD2E871");
//                .addTestDevice("1744314CD0C7B0619F94D44CE2E5093E");

        adView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());
    }

    public void playGame() {
        SharedPreferences savedData = getApplicationContext()
                .getSharedPreferences("lastScore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int score = savedData.getInt("lastScore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, GamePlay.class);
        intent.putExtra("lastScore", score);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is the xml of home_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/homeRelative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/bottomAd"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_banner_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my log after the most recent run

```
 01-01 16:00:32.235  26387-26387/com.rune.colorhunt D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-01 16:00:32.275      652-796/? I/CrashAnrDetector﹕ onPackageUpdateFinished : com.rune.colorhunt
01-01 16:00:37.351  26387-26416/com.rune.colorhunt D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads976472321.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
01-01 16:00:37.361  26387-26387/com.rune.colorhunt V/WebViewChromium﹕ Binding Chromium to the main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {41d00b38}
01-01 16:00:37.361  26387-26387/com.rune.colorhunt I/chromium﹕ [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
01-01 16:00:37.361  26387-26387/com.rune.colorhunt I/BrowserProcessMain﹕ Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
01-01 16:00:37.391  26387-26426/com.rune.colorhunt W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
01-01 16:00:37.421  26387-26387/com.rune.colorhunt I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request.
01-01 16:00:37.441  26387-26416/com.rune.colorhunt D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: --- END 'ads976472321.jar' (success) ---
01-01 16:00:37.441  26387-26416/com.rune.colorhunt D/dalvikvm﹕ DEX prep '/data/data/com.rune.colorhunt/cache/ads976472321.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 91ms
01-01 16:00:37.611  26387-26394/com.rune.colorhunt I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 11
01-01 16:00:37.611  26387-26394/com.rune.colorhunt I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 12
01-01 16:00:37.621  26387-26394/com.rune.colorhunt I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 13
01-01 16:00:37.621  26387-26394/com.rune.colorhunt I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 14
01-01 16:00:37.651  26387-26431/com.rune.colorhunt W/Ads﹕ There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 2
01-01 16:00:37.691  26387-26387/com.rune.colorhunt I/Ads﹕ Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
01-01 16:00:37.691  26387-26387/com.rune.colorhunt W/Ads﹕ Failed to load ad: 2
01-01 16:01:37.715  26387-26387/com.rune.colorhunt I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request.
01-01 16:01:37.825  26387-26490/com.rune.colorhunt W/Ads﹕ There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 2
01-01 16:01:37.845  26387-26387/com.rune.colorhunt I/Ads﹕ Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
01-01 16:01:37.845  26387-26387/com.rune.colorhunt W/Ads﹕ Failed to load ad: 2
01-01 16:02:37.889  26387-26387/com.rune.colorhunt I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request.
01-01 16:02:38.009  26387-26531/com.rune.colorhunt W/Ads﹕ There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 2
01-01 16:02:38.039  26387-26387/com.rune.colorhunt I/Ads﹕ Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
01-01 16:02:38.039  26387-26387/com.rune.colorhunt W/Ads﹕ Failed to load ad: 2
01-01 16:03:38.972  26387-26387/com.rune.colorhunt I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request.
01-01 16:03:39.062  26387-26783/com.rune.colorhunt W/Ads﹕ There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 2
01-01 16:03:39.062  26387-26387/com.rune.colorhunt I/Ads﹕ Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
01-01 16:03:39.062  26387-26387/com.rune.colorhunt W/Ads﹕ Failed to load ad: 2
```

If somebody would help me, that would be amazing. I literally have no idea what the problem could be. Perhaps im missing something very simple and just need another pair of eyes. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You are calling #setContentView twice. Once in onCreate and once in createAd.

Comment: Yeah thats not the problem. I caught that hours ago and it still didn't help

Comment: if that's the case then you should really update your question so you don't waste other people's

Comment: @ChuckOnwuzuruike did it work now. I am facing same issue. My admob ads was working perfectly in past. I have checked in listener and it returns error code 2.

Comment: For me it was this stupid thing https://stackoverflow.com/a/56208452/2439283

Answer (score 37):

Check that your device has a proper internet connection. Without internet connection you will not get ads.

Comment: this is the main reason :)

Comment: its only happen i connect with mobile data. Any solution for it?

Comment: @AnandSavjani if your SIM is prepaid probably you are out of credit on your mobile data.

Comment: Oddly my emulator had lost internet connection so this was the solution!

Answer (score 20):

Admob ad will not load. Error 2 appears if date or time is wrong on your device, just set autodate correcting on your device

Comment: Saved my day! I changed my date for testing purpose but forgot to reset. Thanks!

Comment: I work in Xamarin Android and this is also the reason why. I didn't realize that the emulator time wasn't in sync with the PC time

Answer (score 16):

Error no 2 means `ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR`.
so check your internet connection and still not showing ads then just restart your mobile and check...that was worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Another issue could be an adblocker application as suggested in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36010639/3596576 by @Durian.

For me this was the issue.

Comment: I was using a custom ROM and adblocker was installed. Analytics and Ads were not working. Disabled it and everything is working like a charm! Thank you.

Comment: It is also blocking the test ads when you added your device id to the test devices of the ad request.

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar problem. The internet connection was OK and there was no ad blocker installed.

The problem might be related with your test device. Check if you have another application that contains Admob with your test device.
You can also check with another device and another app that contains Admob.

In my case I realized that my test device has the internet connection but doesn't show up any Admob ads in different applications. So I tried to restart my test device and It worked.

Comment: Good troubleshooting skills, other apps that have ads are also not working

Comment: Restarting my device made it work.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue of the ad not appearing on the physical test device screen.

I switched off my wifi and started using 3g mobile data  and then my ads started appearing on the physical test devices.

I also have a difference in dependecies:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.0
```

instead of `11.6.2`

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is being caused by an app making too many ad requests at once, which puts the SDK into a bad state. Restarting Google play services, which can effectively be done by clearing all data, fixes the issue for me.
The SDK fix for this issue will be included in the next Google play services release. Once your device picks up the update, you won't need to update your app.
[this is known issue of sdk](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/issues/60)

Comment: Hi, do you know if this issue was solved? It's 2019, almost 2020 and my app has a very low show rate (2-3%) and I don't know if it is my code or Admob SDK. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

at first be clear about which type of add you want to load, interstitial or banner ad. if you want to load banner ad, create a banner ad_unit_id on admob site, then use AdView directly inside your activity view as below:

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/xadView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_banner_ad_unit_id" />
```

and just request to load banner ad from your code as below: write this code in your activity inside oncreate after setcontentview

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.xadView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(
                AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

**AND**

if you want to load interstial ads, create a interstitial ad_unit_id on admob site, then use it in below method:

```
public void showFullScreenAd() {
    try {

                com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd interstitial = new com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd(context);
                interstitial
                        .setAdUnitId(ADMOB_INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID);

                // Check the logcat output for your hashed device ID to get test ads
                // on
                // a physical device.
                com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                        .build();

                // Load the interstitial ad.
                interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
                interstitial
                        .setAdListener(new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAdLoaded() {
                                interstitial.show();
                            }                           
                        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**NOTE: important thing is that sometimes we use banner ad unit id inside interstitial ads or interstitial ad unit id inside banner ads, so this error occurs.**

Comment: Thanks, I have already done this via xml and it was also consistently not working. I'll give it another go and hopefully it'll work. Thanks. Btw I was trying to inflate a banner.

Comment: So it did not work. I will edit my post and show you what I have

Answer (score 1):

If using real device, check also other apps, you know they contain ads, if ads are shown. Also check individually on mobile network and on Wi-Fi.

For me, it does not show only on mobile network and in all apps. **Deleting data of Google Play Services** help me, and ads starts showing again. Until GPS downloads its data back. So it worked for about one minute. :-D

Comment: Good troubleshooting skills, other apps that have ads are also not working.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the `Admob ad will not load. Error 2` error

- check your device is connected to the internet
- check your device date and time

If the above two are correct, then

- `restart your device`

Answer (score 0):

try 'disable background data on mobile networks' set as disable in google services, it work for me

Answer (score 0):

In the emulator of Android Studio my issue was the wrong virtual location of the device: once I set it as my real location it started working.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, our company had some settings in the firewall to block ads. It worked when I switched to an open internet connection without a firewall.