# AdMob - Ad not displayed - Error 2

Tags: java, android, admob

I am building an android application that has two versions.One with Ad. and one with out Ad. . I've successfully integrated the `AdMob` in the application. but the Ads are not getting displayed on the screen.

Here's my

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors{
        free{
            applicationId "com.myapp"
            buildConfigField "boolean","IS_PAID_VERSION", "false"
        }

        paid{
            applicationId "com.myapp.paid"
            buildConfigField "boolean","IS_PAID_VERSION", "true"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.myapp.activities.AdTestActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AdTestActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.myapp.R;

public class AdTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ad_test);

        final AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
        final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("A144A6A159A94CC77CE70EC1A874B93A") //My test device 1
                .addTestDevice("8477FA9B6C105C84897FC2717E19A548")  //My test device 2
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    }
}
```

The ad is no getting displayed on the screen, and the `logcat` says...

```
I/Ads: Starting ad request.
02-12 00:24:41.381 15472-15493/com.myapp W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 2
02-12 00:24:41.382 15472-15472/com.myapp I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
02-12 00:24:41.382 15472-15472/com.myapp W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 2
```

**PS: I've a good internet connection and valid `AdUnitId`. I don't have any kind of `AdBlock` applications in my device. I've also read all SO threads about this problem, but none of them worked for me.**

What am i doing wrong here ? :(

Comment: In following question, I found that wrong date can cause error 2:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31811314/4860513

Comment: Yeah, i've correct date which is synchronized from network.

Comment: Error list is here:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR

Error 2 seems a network error... Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to help you more.. You are using latest version (8.4.0).. For me, ads stop working sometimes also in debug app while the comercial app never fails... Maybe, is a temporary issue. Hope you find the solution.

Comment: @GuilhermeP : As i said , I've a good internet connection. and i also built the commercial version of the app. even though the Ad. is not getting appeared. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by updating Google Play Services to the latest version on my mobile. So maybe try updating it from Play Store.