# Android studio activity main

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

When I make a new project from android studio. New blank activity has title bar and floating icon. How to get rid of it when I'm getting a new blank activity. And how i make a real blank activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "Empty Activity" template. That is as empty as you get from the new-project and new-activity wizards.

Or, do not have the wizard create a new activity for you, and just add it yourself.

Comment: That's it :) @CommonsWare can you please take a look at my problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347872/admob-ad-not-displayed-error-2

Comment: But empty activity also have a title bar. How i fix this? Is this a issue of my sdk? Why i can't simply get a blank activity.

Comment: @IsharaRuchiranga: "But empty activity also have a title bar" -- by default, all activities have an action bar. None of the templates avoids an action bar entirely, though the "Fullscreen Activity" one demonstrates hiding and showing an action bar. "How i fix this?" -- create your own activity from scratch. "Why i can't simply get a blank activity" -- because few developers need that, and the templates do not cover every scenario.

Comment: Got it sir. Thank you for advice.