# Admob not work properly ErrorCode: 2

Tags: android, admob

I make app with Admob ads and it not work properly.
When I want to test this on smartphone I get error

W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 2
Failed to load ad: 2

To add admob to this app I used code from oficial tutorial 
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#give_your_app_an_ad_unit_id

I test it on Xiaomi Redmi note 2.
When I use test mode in that code I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happens to me on my Redmi note 2. But it works on other devices. I assume there's an adblocker installed initially that I just haven't been able to find yet.

Comment: The issue for me was an adblocker installed. Until this response I've not fought about this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Follow some steps to resolve this issue:

1. Check internet connection is working or not.
2. Check any ad site blocked by internet provider.
3. Make sure time is auto mode.
4. Restart the device.

Then your issue is resolved :)