# Admob error code 2 - Ad failed to load : 2

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to show a smart size banner in android, but the ad isn't showing and when I see the logs it says: `I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 2`.
I searched on the internet and found that issue is due to internet connection, but I have active and reliable net connection on my phone.
Below is my `app` gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
}
```

and below is my activity class:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, Utils.ADMOB_APP_ID);
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("B2DD8C77E01892E0FF2A672FC77E2FF9").build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

and this is the layout:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/app_admob_id">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

and this is the some of error log related to the ads:

```
W/Ads: Invoke Firebase method getInstance error.
    The Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firebase integration requires the latest Firebase SDK jar, but Firebase SDK is either missing or out of date
W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 2
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729547/admob-ad-will-not-load-error-2-it-worked-before-but-suddenly-stopped

Comment: @NileshRathod none of it helped me.

Comment: Use firebase for admob instead of this google play library, https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start it may resolve your issue. But for **status code 2**, it's definitely the connection issue or check if your account is dismissed or not !.

Comment: @JeelVankhede how I check if my account is dismissed? I opened it yesterday

Comment: There might be email regarding it in your Email account associated with `AdMob`.

Comment: I found it. the problem was that I used adunit id as app admob id. thx!

Answer (score 1):

This problem most often occurs when there is no Internet connection.

Comment: as I said, there is internet connection but it still doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

Some times your internet may be blocked by google adds due to multiple request within few minutes.

- I can suggest use different network like other mobile data connection or wifi